# search the database and put it in textbox

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

Using VB 6 and adodb connection, when I click search for id, a inputbox will appear, when it finds The id I wanted, it will automatically insert all the data of that row to their corresponding textboxes.

Here my code, at somepoint, it does not work, I dont remember the error but I will post it here when I get home, thanks for your help guys.

```
Private Sub cmdsearch_Click()
    findemployee = InputBox("Insert Employee ID")
    record.Open ("select * from employees where ID='" & findemployee & "'"), conn, 3, 3

    If record.EOF Then
        MsgBox "NO" & findemployee & " ID WAS NOT FOUND!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error Search"
        Set record = Nothing
    Else

        txtemployeeid.Text = record!ID
        txtlnames.Text = record!lastname
        txtfnames.Text = record!Firstname
        txtmnames.Text = record!middlename
        cmbgenders.Text = record!gender
        bdates.Value = record!birthdate
        txtbplaces = record!birthplace
        txtages = record!age
        txtaddress.Text = record!address
        cmbeducattainments.Text = record!educattainment
        txtnos.Text = record!contactno
        cstarts.Value = record!contractstart
        cends.Value = record!contractend

        Set record = Nothing

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i think you must loop the searching of records...

Comment: Is `findemployee` a `text` or `numeric` value. If it is numeric, you should not use quotes (`'`) around it.

Comment: `record .MoveFirst` may be needed also.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub cmdsearch_Click()
  findemployee = inputtextbox.text 
   record.Open ("select * from employees where ID='" & findemployee & "'"), conn, 3, 3

If record.EOF Then
    MsgBox "NO" & findemployee & " ID WAS NOT FOUND!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error Search"
    Set record = Nothing
Else
    with record 
       txtemployeeid.Text = !ID
       txtlnames.Text = !lastname
       txtfnames.Text = !Firstname
       txtmnames.Text = !middlename
       cmbgenders.Text = !gender
       bdates.Value = !birthdate
       txtbplaces = !birthplace
       txtages = !age
       txtaddress.Text = !address
       cmbeducattainments.Text = !educattainment
       txtnos.Text = !contactno
       cstarts.Value = !contractstart
       cends.Value = !contractend

       Set record = Nothing
  END WITH 
End If
End Sub
```